# IntelliJ on Ubuntu : No Java SDK Found error

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

In my Ubuntu 14.04 system I installed [Oracle Java 8(JDK/JRE 8u111)](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#) because IntelliJ version 16 requires JDK version 1.8 or later(I had openjdk-7 installed).

IntelliJ installation is successful but creating new project gets error:

> I get error "No Java SDK Found"
>
> No Java SDK of appropriate version found. In addition to the IntelliJ
> Platform Plugin SDK, you need to define a JDK with the same Java
> version (JDK_1_8, description: 1.8).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: looks like inteliJ can't find your java sdk, this might help you. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: So, Are you sure Oracle JDK is default JAVA_HOME ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to go in `file` then `project structure` , under `Platform Settings`is `SDKs` , select it. Then add the path of your JDK. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: that sounds like it would solve the problem for one project only

Comment: Your answer is way too specific. A good answer would say: 'Have you tried setting your Java SDK?'

Answer (score 0):

From the main window go to configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure.Now select the path of the installed jdk under the project sdk option.